# Necesito hacer un filtro con angular y linq, en un proyecto en visual studio Wapi rest c#

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

En mi codigo html, tengo un select y necesito seleccionar una zona y q me muestre todas las mesas(representadas como botones)

Linq (MesasController.cs)

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Mesa))]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[Route("GetMesasPorZona/{idZona}")]
public IQueryable<Mesa> GetMesasPorZona(int idZona) {
    IQueryable<Mesa> Mesas = db.Mesa;
    Mesas = Mesas.Where(x => x.idZona == idZona);
    return Mesas;
}
```

app.js(angular)

```
$http.get('/api/ZonaMesas/GetZonaMesa').then(function (response) {
    $scope.Zonas = response.data;
});

$('#VerMesas').on('click', function (e) {
    $http.get('/api/Mesas/GetMesasPorZona/' + document.getElementById("idZona").selectedIndex + 1).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Mesas = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    });
});
```

y mi html es:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">      
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="tipo">Seleccione Zona:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <select class="form-control" id="listaZonas" required>
                <option ng-repeat="dto in Zonas"> {{dto.nombreZona}} </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="margin:auto" id="VerMesas">Ver Mesas</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">                    
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="MesasDiv">
            <div ng-repeat="a in Mesas" class="col-xs-1" style="margin:5%;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-lg" style="margin:auto" id="{{a.numeroMesa}}" ng-click="ModificarEstadoMesa(a)">{{a.numeroMesa}}</button>
                <label>{{a.cantidadMaxima}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Cuando quiero traer con el `selectedIndex`, lo q seleccione en el combo (previamente cargado con angular) me da error, no me recupera los datos de una lista en null.

He leido otras opciones como usar `ng-model` y llamarlo desde el angularjs con `$scope`... ¿Cómo podría hacer tal cosa?

Intente hacerlo, pero el `select` se ve vacío (no cargan los valores)

```
<select class="form-control" id="listaZonas" ng-model="Filtro" required>
    <option ng-repeat="dto in Zonas"> {{dto.nombreZona}} </option>
</select>
```

y

```
$http.get('/api/Mesas/GetMesasPorZona/' +$scope.Filtro).then(function (response) {
    $scope.Mesas = angular.fromJson(response.data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has intentado usar `ngOptions` para cargar los valores del `select`?

Seria de esta manera:

```
<select class="form-control" id="listaZonas" ng-model="ZonaSeleccionada" ng-options="dto.nombreZona for dto in Zonas" required>
```

Y en Js

```
$scope.Zonas = [
  {idZona: 1, nombreZona:'uno'},
  {idZona: 2, nombreZona:'dos'},
  {idZona: 3, nombreZona:'tres'},
  {idZona: 4, nombreZona:'cuatro'},
];
```

Ibas por buen camino en tu segundo codigo, solo que en tu caso `Filtro` contiene un objeto `dto` no la propiedad `idZona` que necesitas enviar a la API

```
$http.get('/api/Mesas/GetMesasPorZona/' +$scope.ZonaSeleccionada.idZona).then(function (response) {
  $scope.Mesas = angular.fromJson(response.data);
});
```

**Actualizado:**

En base al error que mencionaste me hiciste percatarme de algo, en el `select` tienes `id="listaZonas"` y en el JS tienes `document.getElementById("idZona").selectedIndex` cuando deberia ser `document.getElementById("listaZonas").selectedIndex` que es el elemento correcto.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of null

Este es el error..!! ahi intento con lo q dijiste

Comment: Ahora me da este error, el atributo idZona esta bien porq asi lo tengo definido en el modelo entity framework


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idZona' of undefined

Comment: Ve mi actualizacion, el segundo error en donde lo da?

Comment: Si.. intente tmb, pero no me funciona bien, es mejor con ng-model!!

Lo q pasa ahora es que se me cambio la visualizacion de las mesas no me funciona, quiero que cuando me liste las mesas de acuerdo al estado lo haga con colores en rojo y verde(libres y ocupadas)

pero se me ponen todas en amarillo, (por el class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-lg" en el boton)

Comment: $('#VerMesas').on('click', function (e) {
  $http.get('/api/Mesas/GetMesasPorZona/' + $scope.ZonaSeleccionada.idZona).then(function (response) {
   $scope.Mesas = angular.fromJson(response.data);});
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Mesas.length; i++) {
   debugger;
   if ($scope.Mesas[i].idEstadoMesa === 1) {
    document.getElementById("" + $scope.Mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.background = '#00FF00';}
   else {document.getElementById("" + $scope.Mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.background = '#FE2E2E';
   }
   
  }
  document.getElementById("MesasDiv").style.visibility = 'visible';});

Comment: Tenes idea como hacer esto?

Comment: Algo similar hice hace tiempo, enviame un correo a contacto@omar-mtz.me para verlo con mas detalle.

Comment: contacto@omar-mtz.me asi es tu mail no? Ya te lo envie

Comment: mi problema es en el orden que se me dan las cosas, osea, cuando pongo el metodo getMesasporZona, me lo hace y me funciona pero si lo pongo adentro de un boton, primero el $scope.Mesas(la lista de mesas) me toma la lista de mesas en total. (con el http.get que hice en la carga de la pagina) despues hago click en ver mesas, y ahi desencadena el otro metodo, osea el getMEsasPorZona, aplica las propiedades q le digo de los colores, y despues es como q hace el mismo get, pero lo hace con el verdadero filtro, osea la lista con el nuevo filtrado, pero se me vuelven a poner en amarillo.....

Comment: me encantaria saber como es q puedo manejar esto de las cargas de pagina y como se da el orden de los metodos, porq ahi esta el punto, 
sino saber otra opcion, osea otra forma de cambiar los atributos... los colores..
Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda :) ​

Comment: Entiendo, entiendo, puedes enviarme el correo a contacto@omar-martinez.me olvide que ya cambie de dominio

Comment: Dale, Ahi te lo envie. Al final lo hice de otra forma, sin usar Linq.